# ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

my problem is to understand the `(ostream& (*pf)(ostream&))`

1. why reference to pointer pf? In my understanding necesseary for allocation
2. why the second (ostream&)?

I found it while reading about operator overloading.

Thanks
Uwe

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but we need some more information to have a chance of answering your question. `operator<<` is binary, but your declaration has only one element. Such a declaration is inside a class. Can you tell us which one? Is it `basic_ostream` perhaps? Or is it a class in some example code you saw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why reference to pointer pf? In my understanding necesseary for allocation

That is an incorrect understanding. `pf` is a pointer to a function. Its return type is `std::ostream&` and the only argument is also a `std::ostream&`.

> why the second (ostream&)?

The function gets called using an `ostream` object, which gets passed by reference. The function returns a reference to the same object.

Let's take a look at the call.

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

It is translated as:

```
std::cout.operator<<(std::endl);
```

`std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*pf)(std::ostream&)` can be implemented simply as:

```
std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*pf)(std::ostream& str)
{
   return pf(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`pf` is a function pointer (whose single argument and return value are each a reference to `ostream`), not a reference to anything.

This is used to implement *manipulators* like `endl`.